# Music Player app not displayed in the "open with" section

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am creating this android music player in flutter android and there is a problem in that my app is not displayed in the open with section when a music file is clicked in files.

I have written this android manifest code that according to blogs and stack overflow questions should work however its not.

```
<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="Stoned Piper">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!--
                 This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme).
            -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="file" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:priority="-1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg" />
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".AppPlayer"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>
```

I expected the code to fix it but the app still doesn't show in the open with section.

Comment: Did you add this in `src/main/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` or `src/main/release/AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: @TirthPatel i added it in the manifest at src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: If you're using debug version of your app then add it in `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` as well.

Comment: But its not in the release version too